# OpenLdap add custom attribute type

Tags: ldap, openldap

Firstly, I am sorry for such a question, I am just too new in LDAP world and it is a little complicating to me.

I am trying to add just one attribute type to inetOrgPerson schema. I need one extra field to store an extra password.

I was searching the net already a few days and I haven't fount ANY normal tutorial how to do this! Is it so hard to add a custom field in LDAP?

Please, point me to some tutorial if you can. Or help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

> I need one extra field to store an extra password.

No you don't. The `userPassword` attribute can be multi-valued.

Comment: Great! Thank you. But is there a way to tell some applications that they must not authenticate the user with one of the passwords? My problem is that I need to authenticate RADIUS users with LDAP and I cannot authenticate them with hashed passwords. I need to have plain text password for RADIUS. But I don't want the users to authenticate with this plain text password to other services. How can I do that?